# Hand size and extended chords on piano

Tags: piano, chords, technique, physical-limitations

I have tried stretching my hand out but I seem to max out somewhere around 16 semitones so I wonder how 11th or 13th chords are supposed to be approached. Are they usually voiced within that span or is there some pedal usage, hand coordination or hand movement involved?

Comment: https://youtu.be/ifKKlhYF53w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chords of a 9th  (or intervals thereof) are routinely written and expected to be played, but sadly, not all of us can span that even that. So, we tend to use the pedal - either the damper or the sostenuto (found in the middle on a lot of pianos).

If it's a chord, the notes can be - need to be - arpeggiated, usually low to high, with the pedal activated on the first note. Possible problem is the notes played with the other hand. Pedalling may blur them when they need to be clear, so it's always a compromise.

There *may* be occasions when using *both* hands for a wide chord is feasible, and *may* involve crossing hands, even. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It seems it is time for me to learn the pedals then! I could reach longer if the thumb didn't need to be pressed down so that was promising.

Answer (score 1):

Intervals up to a 10th are expected to be played in one hand. There are cases of pianists who do not have sufficiently large hands for this, in this case you’ll need to make some arrangements to make it work: Either arpeggiate the chord, leave out notes, try to take notes into the other hand.

Everything above that requires you to have monstrous hands like Rachmaninoff. This means that either the composer was a pianist with very special features or was writing for such a pianists, or that the composer did not intend you to play all notes at once, but use pedal and jumps to play the notes as closely as possible.

So from what you tell us your hands are pretty standard size for pianists, and anything that exceeds your handsize is probably intended for you to just "make it work".

Answer (score 0):

If a composer writes a stretch bigger than a 10th, it's probably intended to be spread or otherwise cheated, maybe with the aid of the sustain pedal.

But I'm wondering if this question is really about a misapprehension that when 'comping' from chord symbols the LH is required to play the WHOLE chord, bass note, basic triad and extensions, all stacked up as a 'pile of thirds'.  It isn't.

Comment: I was trying out five finger chords where I was allotting three semitones per finger but with my thumb on the root it was impossible for me to neatly reach to the eleventh with the pinky so there was the conundrum. Then I wondered how even larger chords are played. I could probably cheat and octave shift them closer to the root but I think that would change its name maybe ?

Comment: As long as the pitch classes (letter names) are unchanged and the root note remains the same, it won't change the chord's name.  Also, when the chord contains an 11th, the 3rd is normally omitted, and the 5th is often treated as optional.